# How to configure tkinter buttons to seem more modern

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, config, scale

Okay so I'm a teacher using tkinter to create gui's with my students. My mac users are fine with the look but in windows their programs leave something to be desired. I don't have access to PIP (my sys admin WONT open it up for the kids to use terminal) so I'm limited in my libraries.

Im (slowly) building up some configurations that i think would help them get the idea behind how to configure (I explain its like adding CSS to HTML - doens't (usually) change the function, it just looks better) any tips or examples i can pass on to them would be super helpful. Here is an example of a slider i turned into a tactile on/off switch.

```
import tkinter as tk
main = tk.Tk()

def on_off_slider_action(slider_val):
    if int(slider_val): #using as "truthy"
        on_off_slider.configure(troughcolor="#00FF00")
    else:
        on_off_slider.configure(troughcolor="#FF0000")
on_off_slider = tk.Scale(main, from_=0, 
to=1,orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,length=50,showvalue=0, 
command=on_off_slider_action,width=30)
on_off_slider.configure(bd=0) 
on_off_slider.configure(relief=tk.FLAT) 
on_off_slider.configure(sliderrelief=tk.FLAT)
on_off_slider.configure(bg="#999999", activebackground="#888888" )
on_off_slider.grid(row=0,column=0)

main.mainloop()
```

[example switch off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGLoo.jpg)
[example switch on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHdhs.jpg)

Comment: Use widgets from `tkinter.ttk` whenever possible.

Comment: no PIP required to install? is it native in the python libraries (we're running 3.8). We also use effbot for alot of the documentation (its well laid out and the kids find it easy to do, is there a similar site for ttk documentation that you prefer? (And yes i know I can google it, but not all websites are created equal)

Comment: The ttk widgets are part of tkinter. If you have tkinter, you have ttk.